# What could cause an unfiltered Access form to display no records?

Tags: ms-access

In the course of trying to update and modernise a form, it's somehow broken and displays no records, despite the source query showing the full list as it should.

For context, the way the system is supposed to work is that from a full list of entries, one can select a record and click a button to open a detail form, which is coded to apply a filter to the form as it opens. Previously this worked fine.

Now, although the source query for the detail form as stated shows all the possible entries, the form itself refuses to display anything, regardless of whether a filter is applied or not.

The only curious exception is that if the form is saved (I've commenting and uncommenting minor pieces of VBA as save fodder), it will exactly once display the required entry if launched through the button and thus filtered. Firing up the form manually without a filter fails to display anything even after the save trick.

This is through a 365 Access install, if that's relevant.

I'm genuinely unsure where to even start on troubleshooting this. Compacting and Repairing the database has done nothing to solve, and none of the changes I've made to the form should be having any effect upon record displays (the most notable change being adding a lock/edit button system). Most of the other changes to support these updates have been commented out without any difference being made.

I feel fairly confident that I could track down the culprit if I had a theoretical understanding of why these symptoms could be happening, but my google-fu has failed me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property "Data Entry" must be set to "No". Otherwise only the "(new)" empty record will be shown.

Also, make sure the "Filter" property is really empty.